# dealing with google auth and users

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

I have code that displays "you are not logged in" as a subtitle when the user is not logged in, it then displays the users name after login, but if I press the logout button the text doesnt change to log out even if I close the app and restart it. Can you help me. Here is the code for log in and log out.

```
new ListTile(
          title: new Text("Log In"),
          leading: new Icon(Icons.account_box),
          onTap: () => _signIn()
              .then((FirebaseUser user) => print(user))
              .catchError((e) => print(e)),
          subtitle: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
              var username ='';
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Text('loading');
              } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                username= 'you are not logged in';
                return Text(username);
              } else {
                username = snapshot.data.displayName;
                return Text(username);
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
        new ListTile(
          title: new Text("Log Out"),
          leading: new Icon(Icons.account_circle),
          onTap: () => _signOut(),
        ),
```

I want text in the subtitle to change when the user logs in and becomes the name of the user and when the user logs out the text changes to you are not logged in( this is the main thing that I want but if you can make it display a snackbar when the user presses the log in tile when he is already logged in and a snackbar when he is already logged out)
thanks

Comment: According to implementation of Firebaseauth, when invoking _signOut, the FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged stream will receive a FirebaseUser (which mean the snapshot is non-null). The flutter doc says hasData checks whether the stream is null. So I guess it is not working as expected because the test !snapShot.hasData returns `false` when you call _signout. You can test this by printing the snapshot

Comment: can you suggest me an edit @TranTriet

Comment: I will try to help you with this. But first, it would be nice if you could test to see if what I think is correct so we know we're in the correct path. To test it, in the second `else`, please put this statement `print(snapshot.data);` then tell me what is printed out when you log in and log out then we'll continue further troubleshooting.

Comment: ok I will give it a try wait a minute @TranTriet

Comment: I inserted the code in the second else but nothing is printed so maybe it is null.@TranTriet

Comment: That's not what I expected. Could you also insert another print statement `print('without data ${snapshot.data}')` in the first else statement and tell me what happens when you do the logins and logouts?

Comment: ok I will insert it @TranTriet

Comment: also nothing is displayed @TranTriet

Comment: Ok, just to make sure that the log in and log out actually works, could you please modify `_signOut()` as follows: `_signOut().then((FirebaseUser user) => print('log out ${user}'));` Then when you do login and log out, please tell me what is printed out from the two `print` statements in the `then` blocks.

Comment: I created my signout function as a void so I cant add this code @TranTriet

Comment: but all the sign in and logout are working since I am receiving the info  in my firebase account and the text displayed properly except on the logout

Comment: cant we get the value of the variable 'username ' that i created and change it to 'you are not logged ' in the void function _signout after we await for the signout to be succesful.I was trying to do so, but I cant modify the variable that I created in the listtile , since It wont be defined, can we try this edit?@TranTriet

Comment: I can think of one way to implement that solution. If the `Widget` you are using to render this `ListTile` is a `StatefulWidget`, you can make that `username` a state variable. Then inside the `_signOut()`, `await` for the `auth signout` and then call `setState()`. If you use that variable to set the text for the subtitle, I think it will change as expected.

Comment: [This is the overview idea of my implementation] (https://gist.github.com/minhtrietbkit/788198ad424d40af7d8231a5ce244782)

Comment: sorry but I am using a stateless widget@TranTriet

Comment: Ok, I just implemented a similar situation with `firebase auth`. I copy paste your code (the part doing the checking) and turns out your test is correct! It works. I guess I must have misunderstood the [implementation of Firebase auth](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/lib/firebase_auth.dart). When I successfully log out, the `FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged` really returns null and `hasData` evaluates to false. I don't know how to further troubleshoot your issue, but I thought I just might shout out to confirm that your logic is correct.

Comment: I have changed my widget into stateful, but can you please send me the edited code that I suggested about variables since I cant figure out how to implement it@TranTriet

Comment: [Here] (https://gist.github.com/minhtrietbkit/788198ad424d40af7d8231a5ce244782). This is the general idea, if there's anything you don't understand then feel free to ask.

Comment: I think there is some error since it is giving me that auth is not defined@TranTriet

Comment: ah, it doesn't work because it's only the general idea (sort of like pseudo code) since I don't know the variable names that you use. The idea is that you implement the sign out function there.